# Import data from function to other on python?

Tags: python

This is my example code ...

```
ImagePath = '/home/logs'

def askForTarget(self, source):
        getname = source[1].rstrip()
        image_path = ImagePath + getname
        self.session.openWithCallback(self.doExt, VirtualKeyBoard, title=_("Please Enter Name For Image"), text=" ")

def doExt(self, target):
        if target is None:
            return
        else:
            image_name = target
            image_path2 = self.image_path
            self.session.open(doBackUpExternal, image_name, image_path2)

def doBackUpExternal(self):
        # Some codes here for do other job
```

I need to print image_path2 from doExt ... But I have got error ..

```
image_path2 = image_path
              ^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: object has no attribute 'image_path'
```

How to fix it ?!!!

Comment: You'll need to pass it as an argument. Though it's hard to tell exactly what you're doing here, as you haven't included the calling code.

Comment: I have edit my question ... Please just give me example for what you advice (pass it as an argument) ?!

Comment: Assuming these are methods of the same object, you can use `self.image_path` to pass data around.

Comment: Already I have try self.image_path and as I wrote got it error as in my question .

Comment: You changed it only on `image_path2 = self.image_path`, you have to change it also in `image_path = ImagePath + getname`. And however you can call `self.session.open` method by this way `self.session.open(doBackUpExternal, target, self.image_path)` you don't need to create `image_name` and `image_path2` variables

Comment: But I need to print name of path `image_path2 = self.image_path` inside doExt function before got to doBackUpExternal ?!

Comment: Thank you .. I have add all codes in one def and send the information to new def and solve it issue ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have a class? I see `self` param in methods but I can't see the class. However, I think you are forgetting the `self` keyword while creating `image_path` variable, try this

```
def askForTarget(self, source):
        getname = source[1].rstrip()
        self.image_path = ImagePath + getname
        self.session.openWithCallback(self.doExt, VirtualKeyBoard, title=_("Please Enter Name For Image"), text=" ")

def doExt(self, image_name):
        if image_name is not None:
            self.session.open(doBackUpExternal, image_name, self.image_path)
```

Comment: This is not correct ... Because you are removed `image_name = target` and this is important in code ...

Comment: Now `target` variable is called `image_name` and it is passed directly to `self.session.open` method, you have no reasons to create a new variable with the same value and passing it to a function without doing other operations

Comment: Thank you .. I have add all codes in one def and send the information to new def and solve it issue ...